# JPA allow string as primary key

Tags: spring, jpa

I got a problem with JPA to set primary ked/identifier to varchar(255). I want to join one value from table to created entity. How to properly join ***note*** from *event_note* to *RangeEvent*?

Here is code:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SecondaryTable(name = "event_note", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="barcode"))
public class RangeEvent extends Event {
    @Column(name = "note", table = "event_note")
    private String note;
}
```

table in PG:

name: event_note

columns:

- barcode(PK) VARCHAR(255)
- note VARCHAR(255)

Error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [barcode] in table [event_note]; found [varchar (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [int8 (Types#BIGINT)]